# Can't debug a simple code with Nodejs configuration in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a simple NodeJS code:

```
var a =1;
var b = 1;
var c = a + b;
console.log(c);
```

I have a breakpoint at row 2.

when I'm trying to choose NodeJS configuration I get an error:
"Cannot read properties od undefined (reading 'fsPath')".

Does someone knoes how to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

I tried to reinstall Node but it didn't work.

I havn't touch the heap.

If I run the code from the terminal with this configuration (launch.json):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52364/09646f0e-da0f-4af9-84e1-87984b688e54
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe[14016]: c:\ws\src\inspector\node_string.cc:39: Assertion `(expected_utf16_length) == (utf16_length)' failed.
 1: 00007FF6188DDABF node_api_throw_syntax_error+175503
 2: 00007FF618862496 v8::base::CPU::num_virtual_address_bits+66006
 3: 00007FF618862872 v8::base::CPU::num_virtual_address_bits+66994
 4: 00007FF61872E3E5 std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >::init+597    
 5: 00007FF6187476FA v8::internal::IncrementalMarking::IsMarking+29482
 6: 00007FF618745026 v8::internal::IncrementalMarking::IsMarking+19542
 7: 00007FF61872F8A3 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+5299
 8: 00007FF61872E87E std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+1166
 9: 00007FF61872F336 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+3910
10: 00007FF61872FA44 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+5716
11: 00007FF61872F386 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+3990
12: 00007FF6188D63E8 node_api_throw_syntax_error+145080
13: 00007FF61874838D v8::internal::IncrementalMarking::IsMarking+32701
14: 00007FF61873AA15 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put+50725
15: 00007FF619354C1E v8::internal::Builtins::name+314382
16: 00007FF619354818 v8::internal::Builtins::name+313352
17: 00007FF619354AF9 v8::internal::Builtins::name+314089
18: 00007FF619354950 v8::internal::Builtins::name+313664
19: 00007FF619445F61 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+606961
20: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
21: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
22: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
23: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
24: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
25: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
26: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
27: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
28: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
29: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
30: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
31: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
32: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
33: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
34: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
35: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
36: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
37: 00007FF6193BD780 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47888
38: 00007FF6193BBF00 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+41616
39: 00007FF6193BBAFB v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40587
40: 00007FF61926C0C8 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1624
41: 00007FF61926B88F v8::internal::Execution::Call+191
42: 00007FF61937DDC0 v8::Function::Call+464
43: 00007FF618880B75 node::OnFatalError+119573
44: 00007FF6187E6B17 node::TriggerNodeReport+29399
45: 00007FF6188A0670 node::Start+960
46: 00007FF618909C99 node::LoadEnvironment+89
47: 00007FF618817AC8 cppgc::internal::Marker::conservative_visitor+52040
48: 00007FF61889EDDE node::InitializeOncePerProcess+2990
49: 00007FF6188A109E node::Start+3566
50: 00007FF6188A02E0 node::Start+48
51: 00007FF6186AE0DC AES_cbc_encrypt+149260
52: 00007FF619A085A4 inflateValidate+19028
53: 00007FF88D3C7614 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
54: 00007FF88DB826A1 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

Comment: Can you share the full console output please?
Also can you share your version of Node

Comment: Well, there is nothing in the console because I can't run the code with nodejs configuration.
I can run it from with an other configuration, like this:
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "app.js"
        }
    ]
},
and then I get in the console:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe app.js
Process exited with code 134
when I'm trying to debug.
My node V is 19.7.0

Comment: That error code is for when node fails an attempted heap allocation. Did you set the heap size to something weird somewhere in there?

Comment: share full error log

Comment: How can I get this log?